# Excel/Google Sheets: What is the best way to continue this formula so it will include cells yet to be filled in?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I'm manually calculating the variance and standard deviation of a set of potential investment returns, each with their own probability of occurrence.

Assuming I'd like to expand this list and not have to edit the formula each time, what is the best way to continue the formula in H2 for when more info gets added to columns C and D?

Also, is there a standard deviation formula that factors in the probability of each occurrence?

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The Excel feature of defined "tables" is the best fit for what you are doing.  You'll create a table named something like "Stats" then refer to column C as `Stats[Probability]` and column D as 'Stats[Return]`.  Excel know how many entries are in the table and you don't have to have your formulas figure it out.  There is a slight learning curve to tables, but watching a few 10 minute videos on tables will likely save hours in maintaining this sheet over time.

Answer (score 0):

A formula like this:

```
=SUM(  (C5:C104<>0) * (D5:D104<>0) * C5:C104 * (D5:D104-$G$2)^2  )
```

will do the trick. The key element for handling a range like rows 5 thru 104 is to just specify it. So all the values are brought into the formula at once. Of course, for some formulas, one might need to ensure the empty rows have no effect on the result, so one can use something like the first two parts of the formula to create a series of TRUE/FALSE items in arrays depending upon whether C5:D104 have missing entries. The multiplications of arrays in the formula `coerces` Excel into treating those arrays as 1/0 items so if an entry is missing, the calculation for that row yields 0. Then just recast the basic calculation itself using the ranges and one formula, not the cells and a formula for each.

In this case, if both column C and D cells are empty in a row, it does not affect the result of the formula. If that were the only concern, one could remove those first two parts of the formula as they would not be needed here. But if one of the cells had an entry, what then? If no effect, then remove the first tow parts. If there IS an effect — bad effect that is — on the result, leave them in.

My thought is there would be a bad effect. Remove the D7 value and there's quite an effect on the result. But no particular way to realize there's effectively a 0 in the cell now that there's no entry. Naturally, just ignoring the row isn't an answer either, but one can use, say, Conditional Formatting to tell one that there is missing data.

That means the main point HERE of the first two parts is to make sure nothing stray in the data entry range causes problems.